# locate all rows in dataframe by a given list of single values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this DataFrame where i want to get a subset from, one column in this dataframe is called nodes which is an array of id's.

```
type         id  lat  lon       tags.name  tags.highway nodes tags.maxspeed   tags.surface
5956  way    6985834  NaN  NaN            None      motorway  [45754482, 6342434412, 835929794, 835929795, 8...           100        asphalt
5957  way    6995407  NaN  NaN     Breemeentje  unclassified  [45643091, 45643497, 45644332, 45645616, 45654...            60           None
5958  way    6995429  NaN  NaN  Frans Halslaan   residential                               [45735685, 45737360]            30  paving_stones
5959  way    6995430  NaN  NaN        Eemhoeve       service  [45728947, 4995231625, 4995231624, 4995231623,...          None           None
5960  way    6995431  NaN  NaN  de Ruijterlaan   residential                               [45727385, 45728969]          None           None
...   ...        ...  ...  ...             ...           ...                                                ...           ...            ...
7611  way  759373165  NaN  NaN            None       footway  [943684026, 943683892, 943683902, 943684103, 9...          None          grass
7612  way  759373167  NaN  NaN            None       footway                            [7093157390, 943684026]          None          grass
7613  way  759373949  NaN  NaN            None       footway  [943684024, 943683886, 943683973, 943684158, 9...          None          grass
7614  way  759373952  NaN  NaN            None       footway                  [943684070, 943683935, 943684024]          None          grass
7615  way  759373953  NaN  NaN            None       footway  [7093157347, 943684066, 7093157350, 943684170,...          None          grass

[1660 rows x 9 columns]
```

Where roadsInBound is a subset of a similar dataframe that has individual nodes with lon/lat coordinates.

```
type          id        lat       lon tags.name tags.highway nodes tags.maxspeed tags.surface
580   node    45706236  52.207980  5.288690      None         None  None          None         None
588   node    45706631  52.208070  5.284730      None         None  None          None         None
591   node    45706825  52.208100  5.289390      None         None  None          None         None
599   node    45707053  52.208160  5.289680      None         None  None          None         None
610   node    45707746  52.208353  5.284343      None         None  None          None         None
611   node    45707748  52.208311  5.285264      None         None  None          None         None
619   node    45708108  52.208420  5.285910      None         None  None          None         None
622   node    45708160  52.208431  5.284128      None         None  None          None         None
```

So i tried to retrieve all the rows that included one or more id's in the nodes column from another list like this.

```
out = df.loc[(df['nodes'].isin(roadsInBound['id']))]
```

With a resulting error that

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
...
...
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 445, in pandas._libs.hashtable.ismember_object
SystemError: `<built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001BB3DE29EE0`> returned a result with an error set
```

And i don't really know what to do about this as i am rather new to DataFrames.
So any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implicitly check for the `isin` condition on all elements of the `df.nodes` entries, which pandas does not understand. You can proceed by mapping the standard python set method `isdisjoint` (and negating it) like this:
**Simple example**

```
import pandas as pd
test = {1,2,3}
df = pd.DataFrame({                                                             
    'A': ['a','b','c','d'],                                                     
    'B': [[1,2,4],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]}) 
df.loc[~df.B.map(test.isdisjoint)]
```

**Your application**

```
out = df.loc[ ~df['nodes'].map(set(roadsInBound['id']).isdisjoint) ]
```